# Notebook Jupyter displaying pixels on my plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

i have to build a circle with O(0,0), r=1 and with defined functions of x=sin(u) and y=cos(u) representing the angular position of a point. the values have to be between [0, 2pi) and i have an individual point =/2. with this point, i have to create an animation where this specific point moves in a circular way defined by those two functions.

```py
def x_coordonate(u):
    x = np.sin(u)
    return x

def y_coordonate(u):
    y = np.cos(u)
    return y

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
ax.plot(0, 0, color='red', marker='o')
ax.annotate('O (0, 0)', xy=(0 + 0.1, 0 + 0.1), xycoords='data', fontsize=10)

angles = np.linspace(0, 2 *np.pi - .005, 100)
xs = x_coordonate(angles)
ys = y_coordonate(angles)
ax.plot(xs, ys, color='green')

point, = ax.plot(x_coordonate(np.pi/2), y_coordonate(np.pi/2), marker='x', color='red')

def init():
    point.set_data(x_coordonate(np.pi/2), y_coordonate(np.pi/2))
    return point,

def update(frame):
    u = frame * .05 
    x = x_coordonate(u)
    y = y_coordonate(u)
    point.set_data(x, y)
    return point,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100, init_func=init, blit=True)

ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Here is the final plot:

[image: final plot]

as you can see in the top right corner, it displays these pixels and i don't know how to get rid of them. do you have any idea the cause of this?

i tried in vscode, changed the version of jupyter notebook but it doesn't seem to work.
i also tried to substract .005 out of 2pi, thinking that they might be equal at a certain point when generating the value of u.

Comment: Did you try `blit=False` in `FuncAnimation(...)`?

Comment: still the same. i don't think it has to do with the animation. i'm thinking about the notebook. i didn't meet anyone having this problem so far..